# Есть такое в tw bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap

возможно такое есть стандартное 
на bootstrap?

где большая часть кнопки - просто ссылка, а меньшая со стрелочкой при нажатии работает просто как тоогле шоу  контекст меню с итемами 1 2 3
???
если возможно кусок кода...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ссори фор май русиш

Comment: а зайти и посмотреть на бутстрапе?

Comment: чет не видно там

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-split а это что?

Comment: Shnur, благодарю, ато глаз замылился совсем)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Split button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="btn btn-default">Action</a>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Всегда рад помочь!